# Why isn't my function evaluating to an explicit number?

Tags: evaluation

I'm just wondering why my function is not evaluating as I think it should. I put in the following:

```
dp = {{0, 71}, {1, 71}, {2, 71}, {3, 70}, {4, 69}, {5, 67}, {6,65}, {7, 63},
{8, 61}, {9, 60}, {10, 60}, {11, 61}, {12, 63},
{13,65}, {14, 66}, {15, 67}, {16, 67}, {16, 67}, {17, 66}, {18,65}, {19, 63},
{20, 60}, {21, 58}, {22, 56}, {23, 55}};
f = Fit[dp, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7}, x];
f[3]
```

but as output I get

```
(71.121 - 1.29633 x + 1.34837 x^2 - 0.504693 x^3 + 0.0700859 x^4 -
0.00447611 x^5 + 0.000134178 x^6 - 1.53469*10^-6 x^7)[3]
```

The output I want is the polynomial's value at x=3.

Answer (score 4):

You can just make `f` a function of `x` in the first place.

```
f[x_] = Fit[dp, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7}, x]
f[3]
DownValues@f
```

> 71.121 - 1.29633 x + 1.34837 x^2 - 0.504693 x^3 + 0.0700859 x^4 - 
>    0.00447611 x^5 + 0.000134178 x^6 - 1.53469*10^-6 x^7
>
> 70.4244
>
> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 
>     71.121 - 1.29633 x + 1.34837 x^2 - 0.504693 x^3 + 0.0700859 x^4 - 
>      0.00447611 x^5 + 0.000134178 x^6 - 1.53469*10^-6 x^7}

Also, I guess to actually answer your question of *why* it happened...It's because you were setting `f` as the polynomial expression itself, rather than a function of `x`.  One could alternatively do

```
f = Fit[dp, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7}, x]
f /. x -> 3
```

> 71.121 - 1.29633 x + 1.34837 x^2 - 0.504693 x^3 + 0.0700859 x^4 - 
>    0.00447611 x^5 + 0.000134178 x^6 - 1.53469*10^-6 x^7
>
> 70.4244

Or even

```
f = Function[x, Evaluate@Fit[dp, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7}, x]]
f[3]
```

> Function[x, 71.121 - 1.29633 x + 1.34837 x^2 - 0.504693 x^3 + 0.0700859 x^4 - 
>     0.00447611 x^5 + 0.000134178 x^6 - 1.53469*10^-6 x^7]
>
> 70.4244

Comment: That gives me a Protection error. (Oh, not when I restart. Never mind.)

Comment: Make sure to `Clear@f` first.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.